# newsyslog: pid file doesn't exist: /var/run/lighttpd.pid

Tags: freebsd, lighttpd, pid, rc

We're running lighttpd-1.4.26 on FreeBSD 7.2-RELEASE. Each time we rebooted the machine, and the lighttpd was started by rc script, the pid file won't automatically write into /var/run/lighttpd.pid. 
Howerver, if we start the lighttpd manually by running /usr/local/etc/rc.d/lighttpd start, the pid file will be fine.

Does any know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the user the RC script runs as the same as the user you use when you start it manually? Also, do you set server.username and server.groupname in your conf?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the lighttpd was started by rc script", are you referring to the /usr/local/etc/rc.d/lighttpd, or some other script?

Because you really should be using the same script -- indeed, the /usr/local/etc/rc.d/lighttpd will start it for you at boot, if lighthttpd_enable is set in you rc.conf -- but your wording makes me think, you use a different script at boot. It may even be, you edited /etc/rc for the purpose (a big no-no).